# Okhttp 3 (android) : connecting to ip address with self signed ssl

Tags: android, ssl, okhttp

I am currently attempting to connect to a server which has no domain name and is only reachable by its ip address. I previously attempted to do it by using the library volley, but after spending a day of research I couldn't figure out why the ssl handshake wouldn't work. after switching to Okhttp I got the warning:

> javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Hostname 185.101.92.193 not verified:
>   certificate: sha256/QMgPlAslWrBi1dd/P17AKxJCniO2RfHQ5MufVO5Xji4=
>   DN:   1.2.840.113549.1.9.1=#1619626c61636b6a61636b34323636323440676d61696c2e636f6d,CN=185.101.92.193,O=Internet Widgits Pty Ltd,L=Berlin,ST=Berlin,C=DE
>   subjectAltNames: []

Now this problem has already been addressed on github: https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/1467

I have "resolved" the problem with the following code (look at HostnameVerifier at the bottom):

```
// loading CAs from an InputStream
        try {
            CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
            InputStream cert = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.servercert);
            Certificate ca;
            try {
                ca = cf.generateCertificate(cert);
            } finally {
                cert.close();
            }

            // creating a KeyStore containing our trusted CAs
            String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
            keyStore.load(null, null);
            keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);

            // creating a TrustManager that trusts the CAs in our KeyStore
            String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
            TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
            tmf.init(keyStore);

            // creating an SSLSocketFactory that uses our TrustManager
            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            sslContext.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
            client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().sslSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory())
                    .hostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean verify(String s, SSLSession sslSession) {
                            if(s.equals(myIPAddress)){
                                return true;
                            }else{
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    })
                    .build();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Now this kinda looks like bad practice to me and my actual question is: what problems could arise from implementing the HostnameVerifier like this (security-wise) and how could I solve this matter in a more sophisticated way?

Comment: You could get a domain name for the server. Domain names are pretty cheap.

Comment: yea, you got a point. but i will still wait if someone can tell me why I should not do what i did here, for the sake of learning that is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing to do with the domain name, the only issue is that your application (android) can't verify the certificate because it's private (self signed certificate). What you did in your code is just trying to bypass the validation process by overriding the SSLFactory and created a new one that uses your CAs. 
Check android documentation below:
https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html#CommonProblems

You can continue of what you have. or buy a certificate and then there is no need for this code at all.